# Vaadin UI detaches after some time

Tags: java, push, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 7.1.2 and rely heavily on its push notification support. Everything works well for some time after the application starts, but then after about 30-40 minutes suddenly it stops pushing updates from the server and instead logs `com.vaadin.ui.UIDetachedException` on every update event. Restart helps but for very long.

All configuration parameters are default except I had to add the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true` command options for push to work.

I deploy to Tomcat 7.0.36 and everything is set to default in its configuration as well.

To update UI I simply call

```
ui.access(new Runnable{...});
```

on the UI instance which I pass down to every component from the `UI.init()` method.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it happen when the application is idle (e.g. you do nothing in the app) or no matter if user is active? It might be that the user session is invalidated by Tomcat after half an hour of inactivity from the client side, and that's why your UI is detached. If that's not the case please consider upgrading to latest Vaadin, which is 7.1.8 right now. Lots of issues with push have been resolved lately.

Comment: No, it was my fault - I didn't release resources properly, so some events from the model were getting pushed to the detached UI which resulted in UIDetachedException and prevented those events from making their way to the new UI instances.